# Wait for onAuthStateChanged before loading my route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase-authentication

I am trying to make a module that keeps track of the User's auth status.  It current looks like this:

```
import FbApp from './firebase-app';
var AuthStatus = {
    LoggedIn: false,
    Username: null,
    Loaded: false
};

const auth = FbApp.auth();

auth.onAuthStateChanged(firebaseUser => {    
    if(firebaseUser){
        console.log("user authed!");
        AuthStatus.LoggedIn = true;
    }else{
        AuthStatus.LoggedIn = false;
    }
    if(!AuthStatus.Loaded){
        AuthStatus.Loaded = true;            
    }
});

export default AuthStatus;
```

I import `AuthStatus` into many of my components, but the only issue is this doesn't fire off before my entire route is loaded so its always showing up as `AuthStatus.LoggedIn = false` on the first time page load.  After i start navigating to other routes it works fine, but just the first page load is always returning false because `onAuthStateChanged` isn't fired yet.  What is a way I can fix this?

Answer (score -1):

How do you handle the state in your react app ? Redux ? Flux ? By Hand ? Do you use react-router to handle routing ?

I think you should put your `AuthStatus` somewhere in your state. Then your components should render ( or not ) based on this state attribute.

Comment: how would you wait?